# Huawei modem won't serve Ethernet connection but serving Wireless connection just fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem

I have a Huawei HG8045A router that connect us to the internet.
That router have wireless and 4 LAN ports.
If I connect to it via wireless, I get DHCP IP and I access internet just fine.

If I connect to it via Ethernet, I won't get DHCP IP. After I manage to set a static IP to my interface, I can access the router Web at 192.168.100.1. But I can't access to internet.

Skimming though all of its page of configuration I can't find something remotely related.

What could be the reason for such problem?

Comment: Could it be that some of the Ethernet ports are assigned to a different VLAN? (My ISP router has three for LAN, one for IPTV.)

Comment: Thanks. I scanned through the UI but there is nothing such as VLAN.